# JQuery validation works only on debug modus

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have an empty form and a dropdown list, where on each click, different elements will be attached to the form. I called JQuery `validate()` once to initialize the validator and defined the validation rules everytime the form is filled up using `rules.add()`.

The required validation worked if I type something in the form, erase it, and click submit. But if I don't give any inputs and immediately click submit, the form don't give an error message saying the inputs are required. It worked only when I set a breakpoint in Chrome.

Did I miss something?

ASPX page

```
<div id="divMenuQuery">
    <div id="divQueryDDL"></div>
    <div id="divQueryControls">
        <form id="formQuery" />
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="btnExecuteQuery" runat="server" value="Execute" />
</div>
```

JS - The example below is only for textbox, but it happens for all HTML controls (DDL, Listbox, ...)

```
function _init() {
    $form = $("#formQuery");
    _createDDL(); // creates DDL and registers event handler below
}

function _onChangeDDL() {
    var selectedTheme = $(this).val;
    $form.validate();
    $.each(selectedTheme.Controls, function (index, control) {
        _buildControl(index, control);
    }
}

function _buildControl(control) {
    switch (control.Type) {
        case Gon.Control.textBox:
            _createTextBox(control);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

function _createTextBox(control) {
    var $textBox = $("<input>");
    $textBox.attr({
        id: control.UniqueID,
        name: control.UniqueID,
        value: ""
    }).appendTo($form);

    $textBox.rules("add", {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "This field is required"
        }
    });
}

function _onClickExecute() {
    var numErrors = $form.validate().numberOfInvalids(); // always gives 0
    var formNodes = $form.serializeArray();
    if (numErrors == 0 && $form.valid()) { // .valid() always gives true
        _showQueryResults(formNodes);
    }
}
```

Here is the rendered HTML page:

[image: The rendered HTML]

Comment: I've found the answer, though I'm not sure why. I need to recreate the form and not just attach the elements in the same form.

Comment: No, you would not need to recreate a new `form`.  You're not showing us nearly enough code.  Where is the call to `.validate()` and the relevant HTML of the `form`?

Comment: Okay, edited. Basically I put the `<form>` tag in the ASPX page and fill it up with relevant HTML elements based on the selected DDL value. I call `validate()` everytime user selects a new value and add the validation rule after each element is added.

Comment: I set up a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/frezzz_54/68frctfL/). When you select "Test Textbox", the validation works. It stops working (no error message is displayed, although it says there are invalid elements) when you select "Test DDL". PS: The listbox doesn't work with the new method "multiselect" altogether.

Comment: The `.validate()` method only gets calls ONCE per form, typically on page load, to ***initialize*** the plugin on the form.  All subsequent calls are ignored.  That's why the developer gives you the `.rules()` method to dynamically add/remove rules for dynamically created input elements.

Comment: Okay, but changing it doesn't solve the problem either. What else did I miss?

Comment: Show us the ***rendered*** HTML markup of the form.

Comment: You've used the `$select` variable several times.  It actually represents totally different elements, but in your code, you've declared it as `$('<select>')` for every instance.  You need to be more specific with the selector attached to `.rules()`.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/frezzz_54/d8z6t8ov/) is the new JSFiddle.

Comment: The rendered HTML is attached.